# Summing up Amounts until I hit a cap (limit). Multiple limits are in placed per ID

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE #TotalAmount (
                          MemberID VARCHAR(100),
                          TotalAmount MONEY,
                          Month VARCHAR(100),
                          Year VARCHAR(4)
                           )

INSERT INTO #TotalAmount values ('123456', 100, 'January', '2017')
INSERT INTO #Totalamount values ('123456', 200, 'February', '2017')
INSERT INTO #Totalamount values ('123456', 300, 'March', '2017')
INSERT INTO #Totalamount values ('123456', 400, 'April', '2017')
INSERT INTO #Totalamount values ('123456', 500, 'May', '2017')

INSERT INTO #TotalAmount values ('789101', 250, 'January', '2017')
INSERT INTO #Totalamount values ('789101', 150, 'February', '2017')
INSERT INTO #Totalamount values ('789101', 300, 'March', '2017')
INSERT INTO #Totalamount values ('789101', 50, 'April', '2017')
INSERT INTO #Totalamount values ('789101', 50, 'May', '2017')
```

I have the 4 following cap amounts 400, 500, 600

The logic that I need is to move the TotalAmount to each appropriate cap amount for each individual memberID. My table will contain around 2000 members with 12 months of data for 2017.

The end result should look like this:

```
MemberID|   Month |    TotalAmount|    Year|     400Limit|   500Limit|    600Limit|       
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
123456     January      100            2017      100          0            0
123456     Feb          200            2017      200          0            0
123456     March        300            2017      100          0            0
123456     April        400            2017      0            100          0 
123456     May          500            2017      0            0            100

789101     January      250            2017      250          0            0
789101     Feb          150            2017      150          0            0
789101     March        300            2017      0            100          0
789101     April        50             2017      0            0            50
789101     May          50             2017      0            0            50
```

I am unsure if I can simply do this without a stored procedure or a cursor (which I am trying to avoid. I tried using IF Statements, Case statements and I can't seem to get to the data I need.

Procedurally, I may just need a loop that goes to each member, sum up each TotalAmounts per from January - December until they hit the cap and move the money to each appropriate bucket.

If anyone else have a better idea (don't need the code just high level description) of how to tackle this issue, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Is there only one member id?  Your test data is not complete is it?  I assume you just want a sum of the limits per member id?

Comment: My actual data will contain around 2000 member IDs for each 12 months. I didnt want to write that down. But that is correct. it's per MemberID. If I can get your logic to hit the Limit, I could apply that logic to other Members.

Comment: And you want the 400, 500, 600 values summed for each member id correct?  If so this is rather simple using a case statement mixed in with a sum and a group by member id.  No cursor needed its a set based solution.  Is it also grouped by month?

Comment: Please do post an answer, I tried my solutions in  my IF and or Case Statements, perhaps I am missing a logic that I have overlooked.

Comment: Can you edit your question to post more sample data with another member id and state what you are grouping by?  When you do sql sit with pen and paper first they are your best friends.

Comment: Added another member. I am skeptical you can do this with a CASE Statement alone. The amounts that goes to each bucket goes Up and Down depending on the limit. See the difference of the 2 members. It's not a simple SUM until you hit the limit. The first one has amounts that we cap until the limit is reached, the second one is under the cap (for April and May), so I grab those amounts until 600 is reached.

Comment: I don't understand your desired results.   Why does the `500Limit` column only have 100 for each id, instead of continuing to fill until 500 is reached?   That seems to be what you did with the `400Limit` column, so why not the same logic for `500Limit`?   And why is there only 100 in April for `500Limit` (MemberID 123456)?   Why not 400?

Comment: @Tab Alleman, because you hit the cap limit everytime you SUM the TotalAmounts. For MembID: 123456, it goes like this. Jan (100), Feb (200), March (300), hit the cap at 400, therefore, you take the Jan (100), Feb (200), March (100). No need to take the entire 300, since the 400 cap is reached already. For April you hit the 500 cap again, but no need for 400, just need the 100.